# How to prevent SQL Injection here?

Tags: sql, sql-injection

What would be the best way to prevent SQL injection in the following code:

```
Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionUrl+DBName,Username,Password);
query = "SELECT * FROM DealerUser du where " +
            "du.Username = '"+ userName +"' and du.Password = '"+password+"'and " +
            "du.DealerId in (Select d.ID from Dealer d where d.IsSystemDealer = true);";
Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet dealer = statement.executeQuery(query);
```

I tried to read some blogs but didn't get the varieties. Just need some direction.

Comment: Use prepared statement.

Comment: Read a little about parametrizing your query.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri Any hint?

Comment: He just gave you a big one...

Comment: @AmitPal, for example http://www.techrepublic.com/article/shorten-development-time-by-using-parameterized-queries-in-adonet/

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score -1):

Use parameters for `UserName` and `Password`?

(Within, as a commenter has just added, a prepared statement.)

Comment: while I assume a that he can use google at least a link to the relevant API could improve that answer.

Comment: He already has an Api... Are you suggesting I should do his job for him? I gave him a nudge that should be sufficient from him to discover prepared Statements, and to appreciate why they are important...